# sed deleting everything before ip address of host

Tags: awk, sed, grep, pipe, ip-address

I'm looking to delete every line before the IP address of the local host.
I'm grepping the host's IP address successfully via:

```
grep `hostname` /etc/hosts | awk '{print $1}'
```

Now I'm looking how to implement this via sed. Example (not working):

```
cat file | sed '/echo `grep `hostname` /etc/hosts | awk '{print $1}'`/,$!d'
```

How to include my commands into sed?

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
 sed -n "/$(hostname)/,\$ p" /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your awk example, I think the solution you want is:

```
sed -ne "s/[[:blank:]]*$(hostname)$//p" /etc/hosts

$ hostname
foo.example.com
$ grep $(hostname) /etc/hosts
10.16.161.131         foo.example.com
$ sed -ne "s/[[:blank:]]*$(hostname)$//p" /etc/hosts
10.16.161.131
```

By the way, whenever you write a command list that involves `grep` piped to `awk`, they can often be combined:

```
$ awk "/$(hostname)/"'{print $1}' /etc/hosts
10.16.161.131
```